# What kind of study design is this and what kind of statistical analysis should be suitable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I plan to conduct a study in which respondents will be asked to solve total 6 puzzles together.
Is there a specific study design (name) for this?

The scenario would be:

- First, `user A` will use a mobile device and `user B` will use a computer to solve puzzle 1, 2, and 3 together.
- Then they switch roles: `user A` uses a computer and `user B` uses a mobile phone to complete puzzle 4, 5, and 6.

Then we repeat for the next users.
The goal is to evaluate the user performance and satisfaction and determine if mobile phone or PC were better.

I reckon it is a two-factor: `device type` (mobile and computer) and `puzzle` (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 puzzles) within-subjects experimental design.
In that case can I use Oneway ANOVA for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to compare the satisfaction between mobile and computer. But you use different puzzles on different devices. So how do you make sure that satisfaction or lack thereof is not due to the puzzle but really only affected by the device type?

Comment: I'm not using different puzzles on different devices, but rather the same puzzle on different devices. Two players solving the same puzzle together but on different devices and then repeat this three times with different puzzles.

Comment: If puzzles 1, 2, and 3 are different from puzzles 4, 5, and 6 (I presume so since you used different digits) then e.g. user A will never solve puzzle 1 on a computer. So it could be that if user A is more satisfied with solving puzzles 1, 2, and 3 on mobile devices, it is only because user A prefers puzzles 1, 2, and 3 over 4, 5, and 6 and not because user A prefers mobile devices.

Comment: Also, what is meant by "solving puzzles together"? Does this only mean that they solve puzzles at the same time but independently of each other or does it mean that they are actually working together?

Comment: "solving puzzles together" = they are actually working together. "user A will never solve puzzle 1 on a computer" = you are right.  Without going into too much detail, lets assume the complexity of all puzzles remained constant and all puzzles were solved. In that case, what analysis should be used?

Comment: The users work together. So maybe user A would have had a different satisfaction if user A had worked together with user C instead of user B, independent of the device. Does user A also work together with other users? What is the purpose of this pair collaboration? Since this is part of your experiment, you probably want to learn something about this collaboration. What would that be? Why don't you just randomly select arbitrary combinations of the triplets (user, puzzle, device)? Please update your original question accordingly instead of answering in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very much like a stepped-wedge trial - an improvement to a classic RCT as it is designed to remove bias. In this scenario, each group receives both the control and the treatment condition and by the end of the trial, both between and within-cluster comparisons are possible, increasing power and the potential for analytic insights.

You can analyze the results with Linear Mixed Models (LLM), Generalized Linear Mixed  Models (GLMM) or Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE).

The first international conference on this topic was held in the US in 2016 and written about in BMC: https://www.biomedcentral.com/collections/SteppedWedge

Comment: wouldn't it just be a cross-over trial?